# Complier is always disable

Tags: magento-1.9, php

When i try to change as 'enable' the complier status i got below issue.. please advice me that to resolve.

> 'Warning:
>   include_once(/chroot/home/test/my.mysite.com/html/includes/scr/Mage_Core_functions.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /chroot/home/test/my.mysite.com/html/app/Mage.php on line 37
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
>   '/chroot/home/test/my.mysite.com/html/includes/scr/Mage_Core_functions.php'
>   for inclusion
>   (include_path='/chroot/home/test/my.mysite.com/html/includes/scr:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')
>   in /chroot/home/test/my.mysite.com/html/app/Mage.php on line 37
>
> Warning:
>   include_once(/chroot/home/test/my.mysite.com/html/includes/scr/Varien_Autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /chroot/home/test/my.mysite.com/html/app/Mage.php on line 38
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
>   '/chroot/home/test/my.mysite.com/html/includes/scr/Varien_Autoload.php'
>   for inclusion
>   (include_path='/chroot/home/test/my.mysite.com/html/includes/scr:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')
>   in /chroot/home/test/my.mysite.com/html/app/Mage.php on line 38
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found in
>   /chroot/home/test/my.mysite.com/html/app/Mage.php on line 56'

Thanks for advance..
Vishnu

Comment: Does the `includes/src/` directory exist and is not empty after enabling compilation?

Comment: hi thanks for rply... it is not empty the folders 'includes/src/' i can see all folders and files after enabling compilation.. i have 0777 permission access for those folder..

Comment: Do the files referenced exist?

Comment: ya.. all core files are merged as single class files under folder 'include/src'.

Comment: Given that permission issues have already been asked and answered, I'm thinking an open_basedir limitation is happening. Check [php manual: open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) for more information on what that is and how it works. It's been a while since I've had the problem but I think the absolute path is disallowed when not specified in the open_basedir directive.

Comment: You should read this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store